# PHP array_filter return from multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
PHP Data = $data['Sold_items']:
[Sold_items] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CGST_Percentage] => 9
            [SGST_Percentage] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CGST_Percentage] => 9
            [SGST_Percentage] => 9
        )

)

PHP Array Filter Line:
    $GST_Percentage = 9;
    array_filter($data['Sold_items'], $this->sold_item_by_gst_percentage($data['Sold_items'], $GST_Percentage);

PHP sold_item_by_gst_percentage function:

private function sold_item_by_gst_percentage($GST, $GST_Percentage){
    return ($GST['CGST_Percentage'] == $GST_Percentage);
}
```

Anyone can Please tell me why it displaying notice `Undefined index: CGST_Percentage` and `warning array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given`How can I resolve this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[http://php.net/array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter<br)
"The callback function to use"
You not define function to call, you use it, call it. If you not know how, you can use doublecall. Copyed from example 3

```
array_filter($arr, function($value)
   {
    global $xxx;
    return $this->sold_item_by_gst_percentage($row, $xxx);
   }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
```

Or, you use yourself filter by foreach

```
function myFilter($arr,$your_value,$your_index='CGST_Percentage')
    {
    foreach ($arr as $index=>$row)
        if ($row[$your_index]==$your_value)
            return $row;
    }
---
// $arr = $data['Sold_items']
// $your_index = 'CGST_Percentage'
// $your_value = $GST_Percentage
```